# Query string with keys without values

Tags: api, http, url, rest, query-string

What drawbacks can you think of if I design my REST API with query strings without parameter values? Like so:

```
http://host/path/to/page?edit
http://host/path/to/page?delete
http://host/path/to/page/+commentId?reply
```

Instead of e.g.:

```
http://host/api/edit?page=path/to/page
http://host/api/delete?page=path/to/page
http://host/api/reply?page=path/to/page&comment=commentId
```

( **Edit:** Any `page-X?edit` and `page-X?delete` links would trigger GET requests but wouldn't actually edit or delete the page. Instead, they show a page with a `<form>`, in which `page-X` can be edited, or a `<form>` with a *Really delete page-X?* confiramtion dialog. The actual edit/delete requests would be POST or DELETE requests. In the same manner as `host/api/edit?page=path/to/page` shows a page with an edit `<form>`. **/Edit.** )

Pleace note that `?action` is not how query strings are usually formatted. Instead, they are usually formated like so: `?key=value;key2=v2;key3=v3`

Moreover, sometimes I'd use URLs like this one:

```
http://host/path/to/page?delete;user=spammer
```

That is, I'd include a query string parameter with no value (`delete`) and one parameter with a value (`user=spammer`) (in order to delete all comments posted by the *spammer*)

My Web framework copes fine with query strings like `?reply`. So I suppose that what I'm mostly wondering about, is can you think of any client side issues? Or any problems, should I decide to use another Web framework? (Do you know if the frameworks you use provides information on query strings without parameter values?)

(My understanding from reading http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html is that the query string format I use is just fine, but what does that matter to all clients and server frameworks everywhere.)

(I currently use the Lift-Web framework. I've tested Play Framework too and it was possible to get hold of the value-less query strings parameters, so both Play and Lift-Web seems okay from my point of view.)

---

Here is a **related question** about query strings with no values. However, it deals with ASP.NET functions returning `null` in some cases: [Access Query string parameters with no values in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130541/query-string-parameters-with-no-values)

Kind regards, Kaj-Magnus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query parameters without value are no problem, but putting actions into the URI, in particular destructive ones, is.

Are you seriously thinking about "restful" design, and having a GET be a destructive action?

Comment: The `?edit` query parameter would result in a page appearing, with a `<form>` with fields so you can edit the page. The actual edit request, when you click submit, would be a POST. The `?delete` query parameter might show a page with a dialog "Delete page X?" in a `<form>` and the actual delete request would be a POST or a DELETE. So the `?action` wouldn't actually *do* anything, only show pages on which you can submit forms.  (Is this a reasonable design you think?) -- I'd better update my original question to clarify that `?delete` doesn't delete.

Comment: Your motivation is ... a bit terse :-)  "*[they] are no problem*". Well, I'll trust you, I'll just wait a while in case some other answer appears too.