# ASP.NET QueryString without equals sign

Tags: asp.net, request.querystring

When I have a url like:

http://www.mysite.com/?MyTest=

MyTest shows up as a key in the querystring of the request object.

If I remove the = sign like:

http://www.mysite.com/?MyTest

It no longer shows up in the querystring keys (or AllKeys if you prefer).

How can I determine whether this key exists or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite odd behaviour, without the = sign the QueryString object returned by the Request has a Count of 1 with a value of MyTest and a key of null.
You could test the QueryString to see if it contains the value you are expecting:

```
if(Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("MyTest"))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Edit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130541/query-string-parameters-with-no-values) gives a bit more explanation as to what is going on with keyless parameters (scroll past the accepted answer).

Comment: Since the contains method is case-sensitive, you might want to convert the strings to upper for comparison. Request.QueryString.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("MYTEST")

Comment: The proper way based on the answer from the edit is `(Request.QueryString.GetValues(null) ?? new string [0]).Contains("MyTest")`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do `Request.QueryString[null]` or `Request.QueryString.GetValues(null)`.

---

Without the equal sign MyTest is no longer a key, but a key-less value, you use `null` to get those. To check for both cases do this:

```
bool myTestPresent = Request.QueryString["MyTest"] != null
   || Request.QueryString.GetValues(null).Contains("MyTest", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use `ToString()` function

```
if (Request.QueryString.ToString() == "MyTest")
{
 //do something
}
```