# Should queryparams without values be discouraged in URLs?

Tags: url, query-string

We have a debate at our company on the usage of queryparams like `?arg0=42&arg1&arg2` should be implemented or not. For me it feels strange and I would like to have `arg1` and `arg2` asigned values like `true` or similar.

So my question is if the approach has some weaknesses or is entirely okay.

**Edit:** To give more details:
We are designing an interface serving jsons. So may deserializing/unmarshalling is an issue here. Platforms using this interface could be java-, objective-c- or c#-based.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query string parameters with no values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130541/query-string-parameters-with-no-values)

Comment: You may find your string interpreted as having no keys, and only values.

Comment: I would like to say that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130541/query-string-parameters-with-no-values focuses on ASP.NET.