# Qt QUrlQuery param split

Tags: c++, qt

I use the Qt v5.5. I need http get a request like  this

```
QUrlQuery urlQuery;
urlQuery.setQuery("https://lalala.com/login");
urlQuery.addQueryItem("submit", "");
urlQuery.addQueryItem("email", "email@email.com");
urlQuery.addQueryItem("pass", "unbelievable_password");
```

when I call urlQuery.query(); the url is

```
"https://lalala.com/login&submit=&email=email@email.com&pass=unbelievable_password"
```

the param "submit" is the first param, it need use '?' split the param name, but the param is split by '&'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the URL into a `QUrl`, then add query items on that -- and **not have the URL as a query item itself!**

```
QUrl url("https://www.foo.com");

QUrlQuery query;
query.addQueryItem("email", "foo@bar.com");
query.addQueryItem("pass", "secret");

url.setQuery(query);

qDebug() << url;
```

Correctly prints

```
QUrl("https://www.foo.com?email=foo@bar.com&pass=secret")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's been discussion here on [SO already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130541/query-string-parameters-with-no-values).  In general it looks as though any "sub-delims" **should** be accepted with or without a value: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A

Truth is, it's too bad that the QUrlQuery doesn't have the option for a value-less query without a trailing equal sign